# dhclient fails and breaks networking (uses a weird ip/subnet mask settings)

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, debian-stretch

Yesterday the router on the network went bad and seemed to start giving out IP addresses on `192.168.100.x` IP addresses, it was unreachable, after a while it seemed to resolve itself and was accessible again through new connections, it had permanently leased `192.168.100.x` to the machines on the network. There are Windows machines and a Debian (9) machine on the network. I configured the Windows machines to use specific IP addresses, renewed the `ipconfig` and they continued to work without issue. The Debian machine (which is connected to remotely) has no connection anymore.

The network was originally serving IP addresses on `192.168.178.x`, subnet `255.255.255.0`. Which it is doing so again.

I setup the port forwarding rules again after factory resetting the router and my box was accessible again remotely via SSH. The machine acts as server for the office and is managed remotely by me.

Weirdly though, the machine has no connection itself even though my SSH connection works fine and if I run `sudo dhclient -v` the machine then drops my connection and reverts to `192.168.100.19` on subnet `255.255.255.255`. Only restarting the machine seems to make it accessible again, but it no longer has an internet connection to the applications it is running.

I have some pictures of some things I have tried to no avail.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

[image: interfaces]

After the `dhclient` command is ran:

[image: dhclient]
[image: dhclient]

Before it is ran I can connect and it shows this with `ip addr`:

[image: ip addr]

Tried backing up then removing the leases file:

[image: dhclient]

Tried deleting the default IP route:

[image]

Sorry for the potato pictures but I'm doing this via someone who is at the physical location, I myself am working remotely. I'm at a loss, and short of walking through reinstalling the operating system and praying I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.100.19 from 192.168.100.1
```

means DHCP server at `192.168.100.1` offered an address. The client agreed and expected `DHCPACK` (acknowledgment) but got:

```
DHCPNAK from 192.168.178.1
```

This means DHCP server at `192.168.178.1` objected (probably because it could only agree to `192.168.178.zzz`). After a while there was another try:

```
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.100.19 from 192.168.100.1
```

but now DHCP server at `192.168.100.1` was faster than `192.168.178.1`:

```
DHCPACK of 192.168.100.19 from 192.168.100.1
```

The client now "thinks" everything is OK since some server acknowledged the address.

Conclusion: **there are two DHCP servers**, `192.168.100.1` and `192.168.178.1`, they disturb each other. You need to investigate what the extra server is and make it stop. The term is "rogue DHCP". Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1287268/432690).

Comment: After some inspection, it appears that the TV box we have in the office (which is also an apartment) decided to run a DHCP server.  unplugging the ethernet cable and running dhclient solved the connectivity issues.

This box has always been connected before this.