# Router alternating between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

In setting up my router with port forwarding I notice that the router is alternating between using 192.168.0.xxx and 192.168.1.xxx. Thus, forwarding ports to the correct internal IP# is difficult. The router is a tp-link archer c3200. Could it be related to bridging the supplied router from my ISP with the tp-link router? Any idea how I can force the internal mapping to either 192.168.0 or .1?

Comment: *the router is alternating between using 192.168.0.xxx and 192.168.1.xxx.* Manually or automatically?

Comment: automatically - dont know why. Quite annoying.

Comment: You must understand what processes alters your router settings first. *Could it be related to bridging the supplied router from my ISP with the tp-link router?* Check if WAN address changed. Read router logs - it MUST log the change DHCP scope event.

Comment: Alternating -- on its WAN or LAN interface? If on LAN, probably you realize this because your devices (like PC) get addresses from different networks. Are you sure both addresses refer to the same router, only at different moments? See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1322600/432690). How exactly did you bridge the routers?

Comment: Hmm- My log is cluttered with "IGMP Warning V2 igmp router occured! Not matching ours V3." seems to throw this warning every minute. I tried to turn off IGMP snooping, but it does not help. The bridge mode is just turned on by the ICP after I requested it.

Comment: I think your router obtaines the IP from provider's DHCP. And it is from the same subnet which is used for your router's LAN and DHCP. Check it and, if it is, change your router LAN subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like *both* of your routers still have DHCP servers enabled, so your client devices get two offers and pick whichever happens to arrive first. Use Wireshark to check if this is the case. Then disable DHCP server service on all "routers" except the one that's actually doing the routing (usually the ISP-issued device).

Comment: I tried using wireshark, but found it quite complicated. Instead I spoke to the ISP and they insist that their server does not provide DHCP when in bridge mode. However, I did find the following in wireshark "10.170.168.1 224.0.0.13 PIMv2 64 Hello" - could this explain the "IGMP Warning V2 igmp router occured! Not matching ours V3." in the log from the router?