# home network with multiple ip adresses for same mac

Tags: networking, wireshark

My home network is working on and off, but even when working there is something strange going on (router alternating between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.0.1). Every now and then I cannot connect at all. Any ideas how I can trouble shoot this further given the output from wireshark when I cannot connect at all? All the destination IP´s are to my home router (Tp-link-same MAC adress) - which I suspect is not correct and the reason I cannot connect.

[image]

Comment: "All the destination IP´s are to my home router" – your screenshot ("Destination" column) says otherwise. // "Router alternating between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.0.1" – compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1322600/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski sorry for being unclear--- All the different destination IPs are for the same MAC adress -- my router (Tplink)

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. Remember, it's a _router_ – you'll see its destination MAC on all packets that are _forwarded through_ the router. It doesn't mean that the address belongs to the router itself. (Quiz: If you ping 8.8.8.8, what destination MAC will that use?)

Comment: grawity is right. That's absolutely normal. Those IP packets to the remote IP addresses (network layer3) will be sent in an ethernet frame to the router's MAC address (on layer2) because it's the router's job to deal with them. If you get two different network configs then it means that there are two DHCP servers on the network.

Comment: OK -- any idea how I can troubleshoot the double DHCP server thing from a Mac?

Comment: Somewhere on your network working two DHCP servers, find them and disable on one of them DHCP server.

Comment: @Alex exactly—but the question is how do I locate the culprit device providing the DHCP server?

Comment: If you have WiFi access point(s)/extender(s)/Bridge(s) then investigate their settings. If you running some sort of servers (Windows/NAS/etc) check them too. If devices that picking wrong IP settings are WiFi clients, make sure they connecting to your SSID, not to a passwordless neighbor's router.