# DHCP server not being used by a client

Tags: dhcp

I have created a DHCP server in server 2012 with an IP of 10.0.2.15 but when I click obtain dhcp on the client's computer, the default dhcp server it gets is 10.0.2.3. How to point the client to connect from the DHCP server i made so it will acquire the scope i set?

BTW , i am using Oracle VM. i figured i have to set it up on the router to change the dhcp server right? but how?

Comment: is  10.0.2.3 a real machine?

Comment: i am using vm oracle, its the default dhcp server if i type ipconfig/all in a clients pc

Comment: i don't yet fully understand your setup. Perhaps check if there is already a dhcp service running in 10.0.2.3 and if the service you want is only bound to the ip you want.

Comment: i believe 10.0.2.3 is the gateway where dhcp is enabled..  i have created a dhcp server 10.0.2.15 that i want to use for the client.. but client reads 10.0.2.3 server instead

Answer (score 2):

#### In general

If you're the network administrator, disable the other DHCP server. In general this will affect many clients, so think twice and make sure you know what you are doing.

If you're not the network administrator then *your* DHCP server is the problem. Non-admins should not provide DHCP services. DHCP servers behind the admin's back are called rogue. Compare these:

- [Blocking rogue DHCP in network](https://superuser.com/q/911893/432690)
- [Is it possible that a lower level network can provide IP addresses for the higher level network? And how to prevent that?](https://superuser.com/q/1287263/432690)

---

#### Virtual machine?

If the client in question is your virtual machine running on your host computer and you want the host to provide DHCP for the client, then there's something wrong with the configuration. Apparently the client is visible in the outer network and uses the DHCP server specific to the network. Ask yourself if you want the VM to be in this network.

If the answer is yes then you should treat the VM as any other computer in the network. The above general hints apply.

If the answer is no then you should change the configuration, so your host acts like a gateway and NAT for the VM(s). This will create your *private* network inside the host. You will be a legitimate administrator of this network. Your DHCP server *in this network* should not affect the outer network because DHCP does not work across NAT (at least it shouldn't work; every default/standard configuration of NAT should not allow it to work across NAT). Similarly the outer DHCP server should not affect your VM then.

In Oracle VM VirtualBox it's about setting `NAT` (or `NAT network`) instead of `Bridged networking`. See [the documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).