# DHCP reservation is active but user's laptop has a different IP

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I am learning how to use Windows Server 2016. I created a Server 2016 and Windows 10 client in Oracle VM, set up AD DC, DHCP server and created a reservation for a client. The client computer is in AD domain and reservation was created with the MAC address.Yesterday it used the required DHCP settings, though after reconnection it uses some other settings. How to make a client to use the reservation of my DHCP server (IPv4 xxx.xxx.xxx.101)?

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWfQ3.png)

Comment: Are you sure there is only one DHCP server in your network? You need to use "ipconfig /all" to see which machine was used as DHCP server.

Comment: Yes the wrong DHCP server was used. I tried to restart network settings on the machine so it would connect to the one DHCP server I want. I used these commands and restart: ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int ip reset c:\tcp.txt
netsh winsock reset

Answer (score 0):

1. check which other DHCP server was used with: ipconfig /all
2. disable the 2nd DHCP server
3. ipconfig /release
4. ipconfig /renew

Comment: Is there a way/method without taking a second step 2. "disable 2nd DHCP server"? I am not allowed to do this as I am not a system administrator of that organisation.

Comment: My assumption was that you learn at home, everywhere else you should connect only to a virtual network to avoid problems for your organisation / system administrator - [also see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1536216/dhcp-server-not-being-used-by-a-client?rq=1). And also see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/904055/how-does-a-client-choose-between-two-dhcp-servers-in-the-same-network/904058).

Answer (score 0):

Found that the user had moved the ethernet cable from the docking station to the laptop, i.e. a different MAC-address.