# Only allowing specific IP for DHCP OFFER. Blocking all other IPs with Windows Firewall

Tags: dhcp, windows-firewall, udp

I`m living in a dorm and somehow the university did not activate DHCP-Snooping on the switches. (Don't ask me why)

As expected some non-tech-students plugged in their router and did not turn off their dhcp-service.... And yeah - a lot of students have quiet some trouble getting the right ip, since it's a lottery that the official DHCP-Server is faster than the plugged in router.

Therefore I wanted to create a Windows Firewall rule to block all incoming traffic on Port 67 (UDP) and only allow the specific IP from the correct DHCP-Server, let's say IP 1.1.1.1. I created a Rule that blocks all traffic from remote IP 0.0.0.0-1.1.1.0 and from 1.1.1.2-255.255.255.255. (I did not want to create two rules, since I have seen, that windows somehow ranks the block rule higher than the ones that let traffic pass, and I thought I could overcome this by using IP-ranges).

However I still get IPs and of course also DHCP OFFERS from the wrong DHCP-Server.

How can this be? Does someone have a tutorial on how to do something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want to block UDP\68 instead. I believe DHCP responses (offers) are sent to 68, so instead of blocking on the source port, instead block on the destination, and see if that helps.

Comment: [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/911893/blocking-rogue-dhcp-in-network) : "Blocking by subnet mask doesn't work because host configuration broadcast occurs over ARP to the broadcast MAC address. Responding systems direct replies back to your MAC address, and the first one your system receives will result in autoconfiguration. By the time you have an IP address sufficient to block a subnet it's too late". So you can't block by IP and the Windows firewall doesn't know how to block by MAC address (assuming you can find that address of the rogue server).

Comment: MAC filtering is normally done by routers. Do you have a router and if yes, what's its model?

Comment: @FrankThomas after the answer from harrymac thid shouldn't help, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @harrymc yeah I know that it's done by routers but as I said: I'm in a dorm and I'm connecting my pc via LAN, therefore I do not have a router.

Comment: @harrymc yeah I've found the MAC of the rogue server. (Even send them to the officials - nothing changed) I'll give my best to somehow investigate a bit more an d hopefully I can solve the problem.